# Flutter UnitTest: Two different mocks for the same class

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, flutter, dart

currently I am writing Unit tests for my mobile web application (Android app). The unit tests refer to my login system built upon Google Firebase Auth.

With one of the latest releases of the `firebase authentication` plugins, the return type of some functions have been changed. For example, the method `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` has been changed from `FirebaseUser` to `AuthResult`

I have a **login** function in a `AuthService.dart` with the following content:

```
Future<bool> login(LoginUserData userData) async {
    try {
      _checkUserDataValidity(userData);
      final AuthResult authResult= await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: userData.email, password: userData.password);
      return authResult.user != null;
    } catch (exception) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

So, as you can see I am only checking whether the data of the user is correct or not - I am returning a boolean to check this in another file (if true is returned, the `Navigator` routes to another site, if wrong is returned an error message pops up).

My Unit tests for example checks for a few cases:

1. Correct data
2. Incorrect data (userData is not empty or null)
3. Empty data

Example code of a test:

```
test('Login should work with valid user data', () async {
      when(
        firebaseAuthMock.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: testValidUserData.email,
          password: testValidUserData.password,
        )
      ).thenAnswer(
        (_) => Future<AuthResultMock>.value(firebaseAuthResultMock)
      );

      final bool actionSuccess = await authService.login(testValidUserData);

      verify(
        firebaseAuthMock.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: testValidUserData.email,
          password: testValidUserData.password,
        )
      ).called(1);

      expect(actionSuccess, true);
    });
```

To cover case one and two of my list above, I'd like to use two different Mocks. One Mock to contain a user, the other mock has no user in it.

Current issue:

```
(_) => Future<AuthResultMock>.value(firebaseAuthResultMock)
```

in my test is in conflict with this code from the `AuthServie.dart`

```
return authResult.user != null;
```

The mock is having null as user. How can I change this? :) Bt.w I am using Mockito.

My idea was:

1. For correct data, to return a mock, that contains a user.
2. For invalid data, to return a mock, that has null as user.

Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was just recently looking for the answer and stumbled across your question. But in the meanwhile, I found a solution. I hope this works for you.

I found that there are a bunch of flutter packages for mocking firebase, the one for Firebase Auth is this one: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_mocks.

Also if you don't want to import more packages into your code you can create a simpler version of them. Like so:

```
class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth {}

class MockAuthResult extends Mock implements AuthResult {
  FirebaseUser user = MockFirebaseUser();
}

class MockFirebaseUser extends Mock implements FirebaseUser {
  @override
  String get displayName => 'Test Name';

  @override
  String get uid => 'abc1234';
}
```